# extract string using substring in column data.frame using another column's integer as argument

Tags: r, substring

If I have a data.frame how can I use the v2 values to substring v1.

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("jsdlfkjs", "fjdslkkkkfj", "jdkskksjdjslak"), 
                 v2 = c(3,4,2))
```

What to apply something like this :

```
res <- substring(df$v1, start = df$v2-1, stop = df$v2+1)
```

and get

```
res
# [1] "sdl" "dsl" "jdk"
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the *question* here. `substring` does what you're asking for as far as I can see....

Comment: You are right - almost. I didnt get I completely right. It works with: res <- substring(df[[1]], df[[2]]-1, df[[2]]+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong arguments for substring. Look at ?substring for more information. You want to use first, last not start, stop

```
res <- substring(df$v1, first = df$v2-1, last = df$v2+1)
```